# How to find all indexes of an object in a list without loop?

Tags: java

I have a problem which it probably pretty simple, but I can't find an answer for it.

I would like to be able to get all indexes where an object occurs in a list but without doing a loop over the list.

```java
public void exampleFunction(){
    ArrayList<Integer> completeList = new ArrayList<>();
    completeList.add(1);
    completeList.add(2);
    completeList.add(1);

    Integer searchObject = 1;
    List<Integer> indexes = DO SOMETHING TO GET THE INDEXES LIST [0, 2];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without doing a loop", what's the actual requirement? Have you looked into using a stream?

Comment: I would like to avoid writting something like ``` for(Integer val: completeList)```. I did not look at stream what is it ?

Comment: do you want all the indexes? or the range?

Comment: Just all indexes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Stream` API, by creating an `IntStream` that has all the indices of the `completeList`, then filter out the indices where `1` is not found:

```
List<Integer> indexList = IntStream.range(0, completeList.size())
                                   .filter(x -> completeList.get(x) == 1)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```